# "automatically" detect changes in python variable (or passing variable by reference)

Tags: python, variables, reference

Let's say I have

```
class MyData(object):
   var1 = 0
   var2 = 0
   var3 = 0
```

Data is set from serial comm ( or any other async. process )

```
 class SerialCom(object):

    def __reader_thread():
        if self.__message_id == 0:
           var1 = read()
           var2 = read()
        elif self.__message_id == 1:
            var3 = read()
```

I also have some GUI primitives

```
  class Label(object):
     def __init__(self, text, x_pos, y_pos):
         bluh....

     def paint(self):
        screen.paint(self.__text, (self.__pos))

   class MyWindow(self):
      def __init__(self):
         label_var1 = Label("VAR1", 10, 20)
         label_var2 = Label("VAR2", 10, 30)
```

I have multiple instances of MyWindow class that display different subsets of variables in MyData class

Question:
What mechanism(s) I can employ to "connect" my a label to the variable it supposed to display?  In C/C++ I would store pointer to variable. 
I was entertaining the idea to create a class that holds variable value and variable id but that seems like overkill.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you actually want to do.  You showed a bunch of code examples without explaining what they're supposed to do.  If you're using a GUI framework, it will often have a way to make a label "dynamic" in such a way that it is updated by calling a callback or something, so you can refresh it with new data.

Comment: What does MyData have to do with anything? Where are you using it?

Comment: Is your problem "connecting" label to variable, so that you can display its value (for that you need a reference to the variable in the editor), or automatically detecting any changes made to the variable (for that you could have observers which are updated in the varialbe's setter).

Comment: Tkinter has classes `IntVar`, `StringVar`, etc. and when you change variable then text in `tkinter.Label` is changed (or you can assign function to variable and it is executed when you change variable). You have to create something similar.